# PHP IIS problems downloading file says it is corrupt

Tags: php, iis, download, corruption

I am running PHP on IIS 6 with mssql. I have uploaded a file to my webserver through a php script. Upon checking the file on the server the file is ok and not corrupt. However, when i then have a link on my website to try and download the file, it says the file is corrupt.

I know the file isnt corrupt as i can view it perfectly if i look at the file on the server.

Is seems like this is a common problem as a similar problem was posted here:

http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-php-1pAakBhT/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

M

My download code is as follows:

```
$filesize = $rows->filesize;
$filepath = $rows->filepath;

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-control: must-revalidate");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");

readfile($filepath);
```

FIXED: "just make sure you don't have spaces or news lines before and/or after "

Comment: Unless you want us to use our crystal balls, please, show us the relevant parts of the script(s).

Comment: Are you downloading the file using a PHP script or not? Because if it's a script you might want to check that script for errors and (if it's an IE only problem) if you're providing Cache-Control headers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet* a beer** that there are PHP error messages corrupting the otherwise fine file download.

Take a look into the downloaded file's source code using Notepad.

<sub>* Prize can be redeemed in Cologne, Germany, only. Must be over 18 to participate.</sub>

<sub>** 1 [Kölsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lsch_%28beer%29) at average local rate.</sub>

Comment: Ooo - if it's an IE issue then you'll need to pay up!

Comment: @zaf: But one Kölsch more or less... that's considered the "usual evaporation effect" for someone living in Cologne ;-)

Comment: @Volker you truly understand the soul of this city. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're downloading PDFs with IE you might try :

```
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

That worked for us :p.